# taking input in an array from a txt file

Tags: arrays, text, file, input

I am supposed to be reading data from a text file.The format is
xyz 2/n 
abc 5
now is there a way to reading this data into two different arrays??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your choice of programming language/tools.

In general, you will need to look for a **pattern** to split up your text content into arrays.
for example, **"xyz 2/n abc 5"** could be split using **" "(whitespace)** into a **1-D array** as:

**array["xyz","2/n","abc","5"]**

in most modern programming languages.

Could you tell us more about your environment/situation?

Comment: m using c.and you misunderstood the format.each line has two values an name  and a integer.

Comment: do you mean xyz 2\n abc 5 then?
just like 
"xyz 2"
"abc 5"
. Have you tried fgets()?